# How to find the index of the Nth row in an xts

Tags: r, time-series

```
library(quantmod)

Asset <- "SPY"

data <- getSymbols(Symbols = Asset, 
                   src = "yahoo", 
                   from = "2000-01-01", 
                   auto.assign = FALSE)

colnames(data) <- c("open","high","low","close","volume","Adjusted")
```

The index is the date. I am trying to call the date of let's say the thousandth row and save it to a variable.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `time` function for time-series objects.

```
time(data)[1000]
[1] "2003-12-24"

data$time.1000 <- rep(time(data)[1000], nrow(data))
```

Although technically, that is not a variable, more like a constant.